# Validate a URL if present, but allow it to be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a :box_office_url in a model for Locations. I'd like the model to be valid if:

- The :box_office_url is blank
- Or the :box_office_url is present and a valid URL

I've written the following tests using rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Location do 

  let(:location) { FactoryGirl.create(:location) }

  subject { location }

  describe ":box_office_url" do

    context "if :box_office_url is blank" do
      before do
        location.box_office_url = nil
      end
      it { should be_valid }
    end

    context "if :box_office_url does not have URL" do
      before do
        location.box_office_url = "this is not a url"
      end
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "if :box_office_url contains a valid URL" do
      before do
        location.box_office_url = "http://thetheater.com/index.php"
      end
      it { should be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the model so far:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :box_office_url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
end
```

The tests in which :box_office_url are not blank pass. But the test with the column blank fails.

```
Failures:

  1) Location :box_office_url if :box_office_url is blank 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<Location id: 1, name: "One Great Theater", box_office_url: nil, created_at: "2014-01-27 04:41:06", updated_at: "2014-01-27 04:41:06", description: "An intimate modern theater with 99 seats.", street_address: "1234 Main Street", street_address_2: nil, city: "Chicago", state: "IL", zip: "61550", box_office_phone: "312-234-9999", website_url: "http://thetheater.com", map_url: "https://goo.gl/maps/iSZCP", embedded_map_code: "<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!..."> to be valid, but got errors: Box office url is invalid
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:40:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone show me what to put in the model so that the model is still valid with a blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the allow_blank option

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Or an unless with proc

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

Comment: Thanks! This is what I used: 

validates :box_office_url, format: URI::regexp(%w(http https)), allow_blank: true